# determine which adapter is used on onItemClick

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I'm using a ListView with sections. I have a list of ArrayAdapters, one for each section.
I need to determine the right adapter on onItemClick to launch a method in the adapter.
How do I do get a reference to the the right adapter?

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
  long id)
{
  adapterList.get(x).toggleBought(position);
  //need to determine x (the x'th adapter in the list
  //or somehow get a reference to the adapter instead of adapterList.get(x)
}
```

and here's the code where the adapterlist is created:

```
adapterList = new ArrayList<CartRowAdapter>();  //list of ArrayAdapters
oListAdapter = new CartListAdapter(getActivity()); //BaseAdapter
for (int i = 0; i < cartLists.size(); i++)
{
  adapterList.add(new CartRowAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.cart_row,
  cartLists.get(i)));
  oListAdapter.addSection(cartLists.get(i).get(0).getAisle(),
  adapterList.get(i));
}
listView.setAdapter(oListAdapter);
```

Comment: A list only has one adapter bound to it at any time... and you get it via `listView.getAdapter()`

Comment: If you still want a 'list of adapters', you'd make a e.g. `ListingAdapter` which cuts the list of items into a list of sections internally and binds them to a listview. Definatelly not a list of adapters on a single view, no-no ;)

Comment: Actually I'm a little confused since I have a custom BaseAdapter with a multiple sections, each sections having its own custom ArrayAdapter. The method I want to call is in the ArrayAdapter.

If i replace x with 0, the method works for the first section, if i set it 1, it works for the second section etc

Comment: I suggest you revisit your design on this decision, having an adapter full of adapters is nonsensical, seeing how an Adapter is too heavy-weight of a class to be used from another adapter, esp since you don't need the "adapter" part of it, just some logic of it.

Comment: Do you mean the whole design of having a BaseAdapter with

     `public void addSection(String header, Adapter adapter)`

or having the method which toggles the visibility of an imageview in a holder inside the arrayadapter is wrong design? I'm not quite sure where else I'd put the method and at least I thought this was the right way to create a listview with multiple sections. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: I mean having a BaseAdapter that doesn't have any other adapters in it. You can, however, have many lists - as that's probably why you're using so many adapters - which is fine, and you can put the method in your root adapter. Or instead of it working with lists, it can work with `BuyClass`es and you can put your `toggleBought()` in that `BuyClass` or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by writing an ugly hack.
I had another by having the item position off since each section header also counted.
Also for the adapters the first item on each adapter is position 0, so I'm calculating that as well.
Although it's an ugly hack, at least it works perfectly for what I'm doing. i is the number I was looking for.

```
int i = 0;
int sizes = 0;
while (true)
{
  sizes += cartLists.get(i).size();
  position -= 1;
  if (position < sizes)
  {
    position -= sizes;
    position += cartLists.get(i).size();
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent `AdapterView` is passed in as a parameter to `onItemClick()` and it has [`getAdapter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getAdapter%28%29).

Comment: parent.getAdapter() or listView.getAdapter() doesn't let me call the method in that adapter directly. How do I call a method in the adapter using that? And is the adapter I'm getting the BaseAdapter set to the listview, or the actual ArrayAdapter I've set as a section in the BaseAdapter? This design might be the wrong way to go about this, but apart from this it's working as it should, despite being quite complex (I simplified the code I pasted a lot)

Comment: It's the same adapter but the method interface just returns it by its more generic type. You can cast it to your specific adapter type and then call your method. Regarding the design, Usually you have only one adapter at a time so the design might need some improvement.

Comment: Like I said, any AdapterView (list, grid etc) can have at most one adapter bound to it. Your 'adapter decision-making' is happening in the root adapter that you can access thru your object. If you cannot discern which sub-adapter you need from the root adapter, the design is definately flawed.